# Mercurial is ignoring new files

Tags: mercurial

How can I make new files show up in `hg status` output?

Newly created files in my project directory do not appear when I run `hg status`.  If I run `hg status --all`, I see that they are ignored.  I would expect that newly created files would be indicated as untracked and that I would have to manually ignore them, rather than the other way around.

The new file type is not listed in `.hgignore` nor do I have anything that should affect it in my `mercurial.ini`.

---

```
# .hgignore

syntax: glob

## Specific Files ##

## File Types ##
*~
*.pyc
*\#

## Directories ##
venv/*
.idea/*
.pytest_*
__pycache__/*
*/__pycache__/*
```

---

```
; mercurial.ini

[ui]
username = Lorem Ipsum <loremipsum@dolorsitamet.com>
editor = "C:\Program Files\emacs-26.1-x86_64\bin\emacsclientw.exe"

[pager]
pager = C:\Program Files (x86)\less-530-win32-static-x86\less.exe

[color]
mode = win32

[alias]
; Prevents creation of .orig files
undo = revert --no-backup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that hash is not escaped correctly in `.hgignore`.

## Incorrect

```
*#
```

## Correct

```
*\#
```

The `.hgignore` file uses hash for comments.  Without it, Mercurial interprets `*#` as just `*`.  This tells Mercurial to ignore everything!  That's why nothing was showing up in `hg status`.